# Display max value of a sum using group by

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Cheers everybody,

I've been trying endlessly to display only the max value of COBRANCATOTAL for each year and display the name and nif of the client,
for instance the query result is :
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7vSr.png)

Therefore the  result should be

```
227518698 | Rui | G | 2015 | 100
227518699 | Sara | G | 2016 | 100
227518693 | Paulo Pereira | G | 2014 | 43
227518691 | Diogo Batista | G | 2017 | 2
```

I can't seem to remove the other values, just to appear the maximum for each year.

Comment: Put your query in the question as *text*, not an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions.  Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by year order by cobrancatotal desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

You should also learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Commas in the `FROM` clause are from archaic versions of SQL.